# Careers 2.0 profile no longer shows top percentile for tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, jobs

A few days ago I could see **Top % for [TAG]** in my Careers 2.0 profile, and today I no longer see it. Was this feature removed? Is this a bug?

Comment: This is some kind of bug on our end, we're looking into it.